# DropdownList com checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Alguém saberia uma forma de fazer um `DropdownList` com `checkbox`?

Tenho o seguinte DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CD_AFFILIATE, new SelectList(@ViewBag.list, "CD_AFFILIATE","NM_AFFILIATE"),  new { @class = "ComboWidth" })
```

A melhor forma seria fazer com jQuery ou fazer um componente customizado?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Paulo.

O helper DropDownList gera um elemento `<select>` padrão. Para fazer um dropdown com checkboxes você terá que customizar o componente padrão, inserindo um checkbox em cada .

Dê uma olhada no componente [Selectmenu do jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render), talvez lhe ajude.

Abraço.